# Azure IoT Hub routing to Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I created a **Event Hub** with 32 partitions and doing the message injection over the **IoT Hub** message routing.

If i connect with **Stream Analytics** to my Event Hub and look at the input i get this message: 
***"While sampling data, no data was received from '31' partitions"***

I thought that if i have multiple partitions all the messages will be distributed over all the partitions and not land in one.

If this is intended, then whats the use to have multiple partitions when using **Stream Analytics** with **Event Hub** as input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IoT Hub will use the device ID as the partition key I think.
So if you receive data only from one device, they will all go to one partition of the Event Hub.
You'll get more usage of the partitions by having more devices sending data to IoT Hub.